# Remove block-comments from a file with a bash script

Tags: bash, percona

There is a way to remove from a file all rows wrapped between `/*` and `*/` using a bash script?

I use **percona** to generate a sql script to syncronize two databases, a development one to a production one. **Percona** generates a well formatted SQL script but full of comments which make increase file size. So, just to make easier upload operation I'd prefer to remove all the unnecessary.

EDIT ON January 10th

I solved with this code:

```
sed -r ':a; s%(.*)/\*.*\*/%\1%; ta; /\/\*/ !b; N; ba' <FILE_TO_CLEAN>
```

thanks all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed '/\/\*.*\*\// d; /\/\*/,/\*\// d' file
```

The command `d` tells sed to delete patterns matching the preceeding expression. The first expression `/\/\*.*\*\//` matches one-line comments, the second one `/\/\*/,/\*\//` comments that range multiple lines (this is implied by the `,`).

I don't know if this works 100%, but as far as I tried, it did the job.

Comment: This command refers just to lines which starts with comments or it works even if the comment is at the end of another row?

Comment: I re-edited the question with the script which completed solve the trouble. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[-Try this script-](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/sed-remove-c-cpp-comments/) it should help removing the comments, since are the same as C++ [Here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/local/scripts/strip_html_comments.sed.html) you can see another sed example to remove HTML comments