# GNU Fortran / Preprocessor issue with macros and double forward slash

Tags: makefile, fortran, c-preprocessor, gnu, gfortran

I have recently upgraded my gnu compilers from 4.8.4 (on Ubuntu 14.04) to 5.4 (Ubuntu 16.04) and now a package that I'm using no longer compiles. It works fine with gnu 4.8.4.

Firstly, compilation ceases at this line in my makefile:

```
cpp -std=c89 -C $(FLAGS) $(PARSER_INC) $(COMMON)/struct_parser.F90 > $(PARSER_NAME).F90
```

The error is:

```
../common/struct_parser.F90:53:31: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90
    c_filename = trim(filename)//C_NULL_CHAR
```

It seems the problem is that cpp is invoked with -std=c89, which has problems with the double forward slash (even though this is a fortran concatenation, not part of the C code).
What is the best way to overcome this error? If I delete -std=c89 then compilation moves forward, but I'm not convinced this is a good solution.
If I do remove the std line then I get a whole set of errors generated from the next line in my makefile:

```
$(F90) -o $@ -c -nocpp $(FFLAGS) $(INC) -I$(COMMON)/obj $(AUXFLAGS) $(PARSER_NAME).F90
```

All of the errors are like this, just for different lines of the F90 file:

```
count = count + print_bool_scalar(ptr, max(0, length - count), XSTR(COMMON_FILE_FLAGS_T_VARIABLE)//'%'//XSTR(do_cloud)//C_NULL_CHAR, COMMON_FILE_FLAGS_T_VARIABLE%do_cloud)
                                                                                                                                                                    1
Error: Symbol ‘common_file_flags_t_variable’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
/media/data/Software/ORAC/trunk/obj/read_ctrl.f_pri.inc:4:172:
```

The relevant environment variables:

```
F90 = gfortran
FFLAGS=-O3 -g -cpp -ffree-line-length-0 -fopenmp
```

Any idea what's going on there? I presume it's linked to the first error that I had with cpp. The 'XSTR' macro is defined, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the preprocessor directly through `cpp`. It is a C pre-processor, not a Fortran preprocessor. It does not process Fortran correctly (namely `//`).

To be compatible with Fortran, `cpp` must be called in `traditional-mode` which gfortran does automatically for you. Just do `gfortran -cpp` or even just `gfortran` for `.F` and `.F90` files.

If you use advanced macro stuff like variadic macros, you are probably out of luck, the asker here [CPP/GPP in Fortran variadic macro (plus Fortran // concatenation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41335383/cpp-gpp-in-fortran-variadic-macro-plus-fortran-concatenation) ended up sticking to the old GCC version.

Comment: Thanks, don't really know what variadic macros are but it seems clear that GNU5 compilers are broken for this type of thing. I've downgraded to GNU 4 again and everything works. I find it very disappointing that the GNU complilers broke something like this. will probably switch to intel long-term.

Comment: They "broke" something that was never supposed to work in any specified way. It is a C preprocessor and it is developped for C not for Fortran. If youbuse it for Fortran, you are on your own and anything can happen.